# Prove or Show the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

Let $a_{n}$ be the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of a geometric progression of positive numbers. Let
$$\sum_{n=1}^{100}a_{2n}=\alpha$$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{100}a_{2n-1}=\beta$$ such that $\alpha \ne\beta$. Show that the common ratio is $\frac\alpha\beta$.

Comment: can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Weird that the question has two condition (positive numbers, $\alpha\neq\beta$) which are not required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some first term $a$ and some common ratio $r$, 
the first sum is given by $$a + ar^2 + ar^4+... = a(1+r^2+r^4+...)=\beta.$$
and the second sum is given by $$ar + ar^3 + ar^5+... = a(r+r^3+r^5+...)=\alpha.$$ Dividing these equations, we simply get that $r = \alpha/ \beta$.